# Amplify Authentication (Cognito) - "Error in federating the token" during sign in

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

we are trying to configure the AWS Amplify Authentication (Cognito) on Android, but when we try to sign in the user with a valid username and password, the onResult callback is called with a signInState equals to SignInState.DONE, but when we tries to get the token (both sync or async), a Exception raises: "getTokens does not support retrieving tokens while signed-out".

Looking in the log, seems like a unhandled exception raises and appears to be ignored (because of the sign in state DONE):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in federating the token.
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$8.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1484)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.await(InternalCallback.java:115)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.federatedSignInWithoutAssigningState(AWSMobileClient.java:1414)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6$1.onSuccess(AWSMobileClient.java:1156)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getSession(CognitoUser.java:745)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1142)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 3c924e1f-70ea-11e9-80ca-01ad7f96c8b7)
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
>   at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:1658)
>   at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:739)
>   at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClientCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSMobileClient.java:3600)
>   at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:678)
>   at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:631)
>   at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:510)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.federateWithCognitoIdentity(AWSMobileClient.java:1515)
>   at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$8.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1471)

My configuration:

build.gradle (app)

```
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.13.4"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.13.4"
```

MainApplication.kt (extends Application)

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(applicationContext, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
    override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
        Timber.e(e, "An error occurred while tried to init the AWSMobileClient")
    }
    override fun onResult(result: UserStateDetails?) {
        Timber.d("Successfully started the AWSMobileClient: ${result?.userState}") // Reaches here with SIGNED_OUT
    }
})
```

Repository.kt

```
suspend fun signInOnCognito(email: String, password: String): String =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val signInCallback = object : Callback<SignInResult> {
                override fun onResult(result: SignInResult) {
                    Timber.d("Sign in result: ${result.signInState}") // <---- DONE 
                    fetchToken(continuation)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: java.lang.Exception) {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
            }

            AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(email, password, null, signInCallback)
        }

fun fetchToken(continuation: Continuation<String>) {
    val getTokensCallback = object : Callback<Tokens> {
        override fun onResult(result: Tokens) {
            Timber.d("Got the user token")
            continuation.resume(result.idToken.tokenString)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e, "Cannot get the user token")
            continuation.resumeWithException(e)
        }

    }
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens(getTokensCallback) // <---- EXCEPTION
}
```

awsconfiguration.json

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "Region": "us-east-1"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "AppClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "AppClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have found any solution?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. I also opened a issue in Amplify`s Github: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/942

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my app. Please post your answer here if you have found the solution.

Comment: Any solution please?

Comment: I had a similar problem, my solution was to update the identity pool Id in the config files.

Comment: 2.13.4 is from May 2019. The first thing to do will be to update to our latest version, 2.20.1. https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.20.1 If you're still having trouble, please log a GitHub issue. https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

The same issue(able to login but not able to fetch tokens) I faced while using with the Amplify API.
Fixed By
1.Go to your identity pool and select edit
2.Add your 'user pool' and 'app client'  as one of the Auth provider[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PXL8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your identity poolId is correct (even if you're not using a guest access) in app -> src -> res -> raw -> `amplifyconfiguration.json` & `awsconfiguration.json`. You can find your poolId in your AWS console -> cognito -> manage identity pools -> click on your pool -> click on Sample code. After that my state changed from SIGNED_OUT to SIGNED_IN:

[image]